# Can't donwload HAXM for Android Studio

Tags: android, haxm

[haxm installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNqeT.png)

I don't know why it is not downloading. I did my best

I enabled virtualization in BIOS, but it didn't help :(

[Hiper-V disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCDrn.png)

[and everything else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSFv9.png)

Please help!!!

Comment: i have amd btw.

Comment: HAXM does not support AMD, only Intel. You can use Android Studio with Hyper-V.